# WPF - The button is confused between IsMouseOver and IsPressed triggers

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a button that when you hover the mouse on it, the margin around it gets reduced and it makes the button bigger, and when you click on it, it changes the margin to the previous value and gets smaller.

But when I click on the button and hold it if I place the mouse "*exactly*" on the edge of the button, It changes between the `IsMouseOver` and `IsPressed` triggers continuously, and it kinda conflicts between them and doesn't know what state it is in right now, and causes the button to get bigger and then smaller continuously, so how can I fix this?

This is the XAML code

```
    <Style x:Key="MyButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,2"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#4767CF"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#272C30"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADB5BD"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="6"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2F3439"/>
                            <Setter Property="Button.Effect">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="310"
                                          ShadowDepth="18" BlurRadius="30" Opacity="0.2"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#272C30"/>
                            <Setter Property="Button.Effect">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: _"it changes the margin to the previous value and gets smaller"_ -- so don't do that. Only allow the margin to be affected by the mouse location (hover) and not other user input. The definition of "pressed" is that the mouse is still over the button after the mouse button was clicked. Your code is intentionally causing that to not be the case. It's just a variation of the obviously-user-hostile behavior of moving the button to an entirely different location when the user tries to click on it. Don't write user-hostile code, and the problem goes away.

Comment: You mean I shouldn't even change the size of the button?

Comment: I don't think there's a fundamental problem with _increasing_ the size when the mouse is over the button. But then, _leave_ it that way while the mouse is over the button, even if the button is pressed. That said, yes: you should certainly consider whether changing the size at all is wise; in some UI's that sort of thing can be helpful, especially when buttons don't really look like buttons and you want some kind of "hey user, you can click here" feedback. But if that doesn't apply in your situation, maybe rethink the whole "wiggly UI" thing altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a solution that uses margins to increase the button size on mouseover without flickering.  However, it's only guaranteed to work if the width and height of the button are set. If the button takes its size from other controls on the screen then the flickering can return.

In the code below I use the margins of the border, rather than the button itself, to do the resize, and I've also used FallbackValue to make the button size 50x100 if it's not explicitly set.  Otherwise it's pretty much the same code as in the question.

[image]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp12.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp12"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundColor" Color="White"/>
        <Style x:Key="MyButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,2"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#4767CF"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="6"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=Width,FallbackValue=100}"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Path=Height,FallbackValue=50}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#272C30"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADB5BD"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border x:Name="MyBorder" Margin="2"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" TargetName="MyBorder"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2F3439"/>
                                <Setter Property="Button.Effect">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="310"
                                          ShadowDepth="18" BlurRadius="30" Opacity="0.2"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" TargetName="MyBorder"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#272C30"/>
                                <Setter Property="Button.Effect">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Background="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}"></TextBlock>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Background="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}" Width="100"></TextBlock>
            <Button x:Name="MyButton" Height="100" Width="200" Style="{StaticResource MyButton}">Button</Button>
            <TextBlock Background="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}" Width="700"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Background="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Alternative Solution**

Alternatively you can increase the button size on mouseover using the [RenderTransform property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform?view=net-5.0), which is a more standard WPF way of addressing the problem.  The issue with this is that it seems to blur the button content much more than just setting the margin:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp10"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundColor" Color="White"/>
        <Style x:Key="MyButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,2"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#4767CF"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#272C30"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADB5BD"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                                <!--<Setter Property="Margin" Value="6"/>-->
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2F3439"/>
                                <Setter Property="Button.Effect">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="310"
                                          ShadowDepth="18" BlurRadius="30" Opacity="0.2"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5, 0.5"/>
                                <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.03" ScaleY="1.03"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                                <!--<Setter Property="Margin" Value="8"/>-->
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#272C30"/>
                                <Setter Property="Button.Effect">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Background="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}"></TextBlock>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Background="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}" Width="100"></TextBlock>
            <Button x:Name="MyButton" Height="100" Width="200" Style="{StaticResource MyButton}">Button</Button>
            <TextBlock Background="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}" Width="700"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Background="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```